# JavaFX ArrayList in class empty when sent to another controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have an inventory class with an ObservableArray of type Product, each product containing an arraylist of parts. On the main controller I pre-populate with some data, and system output shows that the values are all there and the array of parts are present. The problem I am running in to is when I click a button to open a new controller and populate the product values into fields, all the product fields except arraylist have data, it's as if the arraylist is being wiped in that copy.

Product Class

```
private ArrayList<Part> associatedParts = new ArrayList<>();
private int productID;
private String name;
private double price;
private int inStock;
private int min;
private int max;

public void addAssociatedPart(Part part) {
    associatedParts.add(part);
}

public ArrayList<Part> getAllAssociatedParts() {
    return associatedParts;
}
```

Part Class

```
private int partID;
private String name;
private double price;
private int inStock;
private int min;
private int max;
```

Inventory Class

```
private static ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public ObservableList<Product> getAllProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void addPart(Part part) {
    allParts.add(part);
}

public void addProduct(Product prod) {
    products.add(prod);
}

public Part lookupPart(int partid) {
    if (partid > allParts.size() || partid < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return allParts.get(partid-1);
    }
}
```

MainController

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    if (firstLoad) {
        inventory.addPart(new Part(1,"Widget",1.13,5,1,8));
        inventory.addPart(new Part(2,"Sprocket",2.88,5,1,8));
        inventory.addPart(new Part(3,"Gear",3.46,5,1,8));

        inventory.addProduct(new Product(1,"Dohicky",13.34,3,1,5));
        inventory.lookupProduct(1).addAssociatedPart(inventory.lookupPart(1));
        inventory.lookupProduct(1).addAssociatedPart(inventory.lookupPart(2));
        inventory.addProduct(new Product(2,"Thingamajig",24.12,3,1,5));
        inventory.lookupProduct(1).addAssociatedPart(inventory.lookupPart(2));
        inventory.lookupProduct(1).addAssociatedPart(inventory.lookupPart(3));
    }
    tblProducts.setItems(inventory.getAllProducts());
}

@FXML
private void handleAddMod(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = null;


    if (event.getSource() == btnProdMod && tblProducts.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
        Product prod = tblProducts.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("ModifyProduct.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        loader.<ModifyProductController>getController().displayProd(prod);
    }

    if (root != null) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

At this point, System.out.println() on any given product will return valid information, and even on the product getallassociatedparts size shows that it is populated.

ModifyProductController

```
public void displayProd (Product prod) {
    System.out.println(prod.getName());
    System.out.println(prod.getAllAssociatedParts().size());
}
```

At this point, the product name (and any other fields within it) will show, but there is nothing in the associatedParts list.

For instance, if I passed part 1 as seen above, the system output shows me Widget, followed by a 0.

Comment: How is the inventory products loaded into `tblProducts`?

Comment: tblProducts.setItems(inventory.getAllProducts());

Comment: I took the time to create compilable code from this (took quite long, you're missing a lot of parts). But after running the app, the issue wasn't reproducible. Voting for close. There are some weird things in your code btw: `products` is a `static` field with a non-static getter. The fields of type `List` can and should be `final`. You're checking the `source`of the event instead of simply adding the event handler only to the button you compare with.Furthermore the second if's body could be integrated in the first one without changing the results.Also I'd expect`firstLoad`to be set to `false`.

Comment: It's weird that `allParts` is never declared, and `lookupProduct()` is also not defined. It is also unclear when the first "at this point" is, that you know for sure there are parts, and when the second "at this point" is, which the parts are missing. It is also unclear what `I passed part 1 as seen above, the system output shows me Widget, followed by a 0.` mean.

Comment: @fabian you are entirely correct, it does appear to work, I am an idiot and appears I was only testing on product id 2, when I looked this morning I noticed in my main initialize that I accidentally assigned all parts to product 1, so prod 2 didn't have anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is for me to chill out and take a break from the code, @fabian pointed out it worked fine when he tried it, so when looking back over the code I noticed that I had accidentally assigned all parts to product 1, and like an idiot I had only tested on product 2 (last on list so closer to the button? not sure lol)

After updating the main controller parts to lookupProduct(2) instead of 1, it worked just fine:

```
    inventory.lookupProduct(2).addAssociatedPart(inventory.lookupPart(2));
    inventory.lookupProduct(2).addAssociatedPart(inventory.lookupPart(3));
```